# Is the **pdftopng.exe** still included in TeXLive 2017?

Tags: texlive-2017

In TeXlive 2016, I normally convert pdf pages to png image using pdftopng.exe which comes with TeX distribution. However, it seems that there is no `pdftopng.exe` available in TeXlive 2017. Is the `pdftopng` really excluded from TeXlive 2017?

Comment: Is it for web? Then using some other approaches, like mathjax might be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find pdftopng in my texlive 2016 installation, but there and in the texlive 2017 on Windows is pdftocairo, see here for the details: [pdftocairo.pdf at tug.org](https://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/support/wintools/pdftocairo.pdf). Probably it can provide at least the same service. The manual says:

> pdftocairo [options] PDF-file [output-file]

and you can have a PNG file as output.

Comment: It is weird that I did have pdftopng.exe in my previous distribution, TeXlive 2016!